# Putting an operator inside of alert() in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm going through a loops tutorial on javascript.info and I'm confused why the following happens:

```
let i = 3;
while (i) alert(i--);
```

result: 3, 2, and 1

Why is the first result 3 and not 2?

Thanks.

Comment: because it says 'i--' and not '--i'

Comment: The decrement operator (--) decrements (subtracts one from) its operand and returns a value. So i is first decremented and then it is shown in alert

Comment: `i--` returns the value of `i` prior to decrementing it. `--i` decrements `i` and then returns the decremented value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Decrement (--) operator

This is what MDN [docs say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement)

> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x--), the
> decrement operator decrements and returns the value before
> decrementing.
>
> If used prefix, with operator before operand (for example, --x), the
> decrement operator decrements and returns the value after
> decrementing.

What you see is the value before decrementing, thats how it works. If you want the other way use `--i`

Answer (score 0):

The -- operators work 2 different ways.

The following code will decrease by 1 after it runs through:

```
let i = 3;
while (i) alert(i--); //3
```

The following code will decrease by 1 before it runs through:

```
let i = 3;
while (i) alert(--i); //2
```

I would also suggest doing this in the loop rather than the alert.

Example:

```
let i = 3;
while (--i >= 0) alert(i); //2
```